# Emacs Keybindings for all Text Inputs

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, emacs

I type with ten fingers. I try to avoid all keys on the keyboard which are not easily accessible:

- <kbd>Pos1</kbd>
- <kbd>End1</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- ...

Up to now my fingers like the emacs key bindings, since they work in the editor and with bash:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>: beginning of line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>: end of line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>: kill from cursor until end of line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>: insert killed content (paste)

I am currently switching from emacs to pycharm.

Now I could modify pycharm (there is already a config with emacs key bindings). But still there are a lot of other applications like webbrowser, email client, ... which don't understand the key bindings.

Ain't there a way to have the fundamental things available in all text inputs?

**Update**
I am not fixed to the emacs keybings. I am still young enough to learn a different one. But it needs to be accessible for ten finger typers: I don't want to leave keys <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> with my forefingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web several times for some minutes, the best page I found was [this](https://forum.colemak.com/viewtopic.php?id=1438)

It explains the remapping of keys for keyboard layout colemark. But it can be used with QWERTY/QWERTZ, too.

The remapping of above forum posting gets done with the command line tool `setxkbmap`.

Update: I did not use `setxkbmap`, since it felt like a tool from the last century. Today (year 2016) Linux has [IBus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus). But up to now I found no time to solve my idea with ibus.

There is a tool which looks promising (ibus typing booster). But I have not tried it up to now.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the link here?

Comment: I found that you've updated the answer. If you still think this answers the question, explain it. Otherwise I suggest to remove it

Comment: @Anwar at the bottom of the question there is an update to the question. The goal is to have easy cursor movements, they can be different than the one use by emacs. Yes, the heading of the question is missleading.

Comment: @guettli If that is the case, accept your own answer please. Leaving question un-answered (as there is no upvoted and accepted answer) is not beneficial for the site. Thanks